# Laravel 4.0 - Php Artisan Serve function not working after installing three public modules

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm following this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/combining-laravel-4-and-backbone/) to install Laravel correctly and I am up to just before part 2 starts. The command `php artisan serve` that needs to be run chucks out the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider' not found in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 123
>       {"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider' not found","file":"/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php","line":123}}

Line 123 is shown below:

```
public function createProvider(Application $app, $provider)
{
    return new $provider($app); // This is line 123
}
```

I previously had this issue and resolved it by removing the 'scripts' section of my `composer.json` but now the error is appearing with it being there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i found solution on this url.

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=38246#p38246

delete scripts from your composer.json

Answer (score 0):

This can also mean that the actual version of Laravel you have running is 4.0 and not 4.1.  Check your composer.json file to make sure you require Laravel 4.1.*.  Some packages may not work yet with 4.1, so sometimes you may need to go back to version 4.0, which would cause something like this to happen.